# How to colorize highcharts above threshold value?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

How can I colorize an area chart above a threshold value along the y-axis with highcharts just like in the figure? I am sure about its chart type also. Is it the area chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `area` series type with zones, for example:

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    type: 'area',
    zones: [{
        value: 5,
        color: 'green'
    }, {
        color: 'red'
    }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u1pg9qdj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.zones